Unable to initialize Spark CatBoostClassifier with parameters
I am trying to create a CatBoostClassifier using catboost_spark. In the regular Catboost package, parameters such as learning_rate, loss_function, num_leaves, etc. can be included when creating the CatBoostClassifier instance. When trying to do this for the catboost_spark version, it's giving an unexpected keyword argument error. I have pasted the error below. Is there a way to include these parameters when creating the class instance, or is there another way to include these?
`----> 8 model = catboost_spark.CatBoostClassifier(learning_rate=configs['catboost']['learning_rate'])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/__init__.py:135, in keyword_only.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    133     raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
    134 self._input_kwargs = kwargs
--> 135 return func(self, **kwargs)

TypeError: CatBoostClassifier.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'learning_rate'`

I tried several different parameters, and all gave the same unexpected keyword argument error.
